# Theme file (thmutil) did not reconize my WixLocalization string

Tags: xml, windows, themes, bootstrapper, wix4

If this issue is a bug:

Which version of WiX are you building with?
4.0.1+6e6eb478

Which version of Visual Studio are you building with (if any)?
2022

Which version of the WiX Toolset Visual Studio Extension are you building with (if any)?
4

Which version of .NET are you building with?
6

If the problem occurs when installing your packages built with WiX, what is the version of Windows the package is running on?
10

Describe the problem and the steps to reproduce it.

bootstrapper have a theme xml that needs to read my WixLocalization string
try to add to Editbox StringId like in website

```
<Editbox Name="InstallFolder" X="11" Y="143" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" FileSystemAutoComplete="yes" StringId="DefaultPath" />
```

in my product.en-us.wxl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" Language="1033" xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxl">.
<String Id="DefaultPath" Value="C:\Program Files" />
</WixLocalization>
```

No error or warning after build, just the installer does not open
Describe the behavior you expected and how it differed from the actual behavior.
after build the installer work fine and i see the default path in Editbox as text

And what is String resource
And how I make a default value to editbox

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation schema String elements should be declared under Theme element in the theme file.
https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/thmutil/editbox/

```
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/thmutil">
<String Id="9">C:\Program Files (x86)\test"</String>
<Editbox Name="InstallFolder" X="200" Y="121" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="7" FileSystemAutoComplete="yes" StringId="9"/>
```

The Id must be an integer, if not the bootstrapper don't run after being builded.

But that does not seem to be working either, the Editbox is not populated with default value with it. So I may be miss some information too or the attribute is broken.